# version of java SDK in javaFX SDK

Tags: java, javafx

A javaFX project in net.beans allows you to write normal Java classes (POJOs, not the FX ones), so I assume the FX SDK includes some version of Java SDK. The thing I don't understand is why are some classes like javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter missing.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that the JavaFX SDK includes the standard JDK.  If you have NetBeans installed, you probably have the standard JDK installed, as it is listed in the software requirements for NetBeans ([here](http://netbeans.org/community/releases/69/relnotes.html)).  I don't know why some classes would be missing, but the entire JDK should be available.  Someone please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, the problem is some classes are not available when writing Java in JavaFX project. I noticed it when I copied my Java code (the non-GUI one) to the JavaFX project.